# background not covering the entire webpage

Tags: html, css

while i was fixing up my website i noticed this odd thing happening: [website is shown with a empty blank bar at the right. the background image is not covering it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SOD53.png)
if it helps, i work with a 2560 x 1600 resolution. i have also used this css layout generator: https://layout.bradwoods.io/customize

i have tried to fix this by changing website layout to my laptop's resolution but it only ended up turning wonky, with the left bar going farther then i wanted. i've also tried using `background-repeat: repeat;` but it didn't change anything.

here's the snippet, i dont know if the background will show properly.

```css
<style type="text/css">
.body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 64px;
    line-height: 24m;
    color: black;
    width: 2560px;
    height: 1600px;
    
    

}
.layout {
  width: 1366px;
  height: 768px;

  display: grid;
  grid:
    "header header header" auto
    "leftSide body rightSide" 1fr
    "footer footer footer" auto
    / auto 1fr auto;
  gap: 8px;
   
   background-image: url("backgrounds/tumblr_mex6qjrEDw1rbvno1.png");
 background-repeat: repeat 
}

.header { grid-area: header; 
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
}

#float {
text-shadow: -1px 0 #000, 0 1px #000, 1px 0 #000, 0 -1px #000, 0 0;
 font-style: italic;
 font-size:2em;
 font-weight:bold; 
 color: #fff;
    animation-name: floating;
    animation-duration: 3s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}

@keyframes floating {
    0% { transform: translate(0,  0px); }
    50%  { transform: translate(0, 15px); }
    100%   { transform: translate(0, -0px); }    
}



.leftSide { grid-area: leftSide; 
width:auto;
  border:2px groove pink;
  margin-top:5px;
  margin-bottom:5px;
  height:auto;
  padding:10px;
  box-shadow: -1px -1.4px 1px inset #9e9699, 2px 3px 1.5px inset white, 0px 0px 2px #cccacb;  
  background: rgb(255,244,248);
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(255,244,248,1) 0%, rgba(255,214,229,1) 100%);

}
.body { grid-area: body;
  margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    line-height: 24m;
    color: black;
    width: 2560px
    height: 1600px}

.rightSide { grid-area: rightSide; 
width:auto;
  border:2px groove pink;;
  margin-top:5px;
  margin-bottom:5px;
  height:auto;
  padding:10px;
  box-shadow: -1px -1.4px 1px inset #9e9699, 2px 3px 1.5px inset white, 0px 0px 2px #cccacb;  
  background: rgb(255,244,248);
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(255,244,248,1) 0%, rgba(255,214,229,1) 100%); 
    }

.footer { grid-area: footer; }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title> TOOME </title>
    <link href="home.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
     <body>
    <section class="layout">
        <div class="header"> <div id="float"> <img src="images/toomenutsbetter.png" style="width:auto;height:288px;"> </div> </div>
        <div class="leftSide"><center><img src="images/tumblr_ma31eljILG1qid2nw540.gif"></center> <p style="font-family: ms ui gothic;"> welcome to my super awesome pawsome
        <br> website where i do what i want forever...
        <br> (￣y▽￣)╭ ohohoho.....
        <br>
            <br> <img src= "images/construction.gif">
        </div>
  <div class="body"><P>i farted </P></div>
  <div class="rightSide"><P>i farted really loud </P></div>
  <div class="footer"> <P>i farted </P>  </div>
</section>
</body>

    
    
    </head>
 
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    </html>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet** using the `<>` icon.. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: Minimal example in a stack snippet, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do try with the below given changes in the body where you missed few syntax

```
.body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 64px;
        line-height: 24m;
        color: black;
        width: 2560px; /* Add semicolon */
        height: 1600px; /* Add semicolon */
    }
```

and do change the height and width in layout to 100

```
.layout {
        width: 100%; /* Change to 100% */
        height: 100%; /* Change to 100% */
        /* other css */
       }
```

Move the section tag to be a direct child of body tag.

```
<body>
    <section class="layout">
        <!-- Content goes here -->
    </section>
</body>
```